# Why isn't my mongoose validation method on the model not working with Joi?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

**The Problem**:

I have a basic authentication flow set up. 
I have this custom method on my users model:

```
userSchema.methods.joiValidate = function() {
  console.log(typeof this.username);
  const Joi = require("joi");
  const schema = {
    username: Joi.types.String.min(6)
      .max(24)
      .required(),
    email: Joi.types.String.email().required(),
    password: Joi.types.String.min(8)
      .max(30)
      .regex(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}/)
      .required()
  };
  return Joi.validate(this, schema);
};
```

But it isn't working as expected.

When I create a new user and validate it like so:

```
const invalidUser = new User({
      username: "bob",
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      password: "test123"
    });
invalidUser.joiValidate();
```

I get this error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'String' of undefined`

I don't know why? `this` in my method refers to exact this user and it has all required fields on it (username, email and password) when I console.log it in the model (document) itself. 
**I also tried to `Joi.validate(this.toObject(), schema)` on the method but that doesn't change anything.**

Could anybody explain me what is going on and why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone curious what the problem was -
I somehow messed up the whole syntax of joi (Copied some old code I found on StackOverflow, LOL).

I fixed it like this:

```js
    userSchema.methods.joiValidate = function() {
    
      // pull out just the properties that has to be checked (generated fields from mongoose we ignore)
      const { username, email, password } = this;
      const user = { username, email, password };
      const Joi = require("joi");
      const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        username: Joi.string()
          .min(6)
          .max(24)
          .required(),
        email: Joi.string()
          .email()
          .required(),
        password: Joi.string()
          .min(8)
          .max(30)
          .regex(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}/)
          .required(),
        _id: Joi.string()
      });
    
      return Joi.validate(user, schema, { abortEarly: false });
    };
```